# Unable to access RPi SSH from iMac, help?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh, failure

I'm bit of a newb to Pi and I've setup a RPi 3 Model B with Raspbian. I followed this guide (see below) to setup SSH correctly, however, when I try to access the Pi with the correct credentials (using the Termius SSH client) I receive the returned message "Connection Closed with Status: Authentication has failed of Raspberry Pi" I'm stumped, I've followed all the recommended troubleshooting and can't figure out why its not authenticating. Has anyone experienced this before?

Edit: Apparently I did not ask a real question, so here it is. I have done the following:

```
2. Enable SSH
```

As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled by default. It can be enabled manually from the desktop:

```
Launch Raspberry Pi Configuration from the Preferences menu
Navigate to the Interfaces tab
Select Enabled next to SSH
Click OK
```

Alternatively, raspi-config can be used in the terminal:

```
Enter sudo raspi-config in a terminal window
Select Interfacing Options
Navigate to and select SSH
Choose Yes
Select Ok
Choose Finish
```

Then I used my Terminal client on my iMac, entered the correct details, the IP address for the Pi was taken from the DHCP Server tab in my router (RT-AX88U ASUS WRT-Merlin), I have also verified the IP address by performing a LAN Scan, I then entered the username and password and received an authentication error. I have verified that I am using the correct password and user name. I cannot access the Pi using SSH from other clients on the same network. I can access my QNAP NAS, Router, and iMac from SSH/terminal clients from devices on the same network, I just cannot access the Pi, is there anything else I could try? What are my options? Thank you.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md

Comment: Here is what I've done https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md

Comment: To verify your environment you can check with Raspbian Buster Lite https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103527/79866.

Comment: @Milliways can someone else help?? Anyone? Edit: what I wrote is what I DID ... lol

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GVyok2g.png

Comment: Okay, it turns out that a simple reboot seems to have  fixed the issue.

Comment: @Ingo thank you for trying to help, appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a problem that was fixed by a reboot.

Comment: Please be reminded of the [*be nice*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/conduct) policy.

Comment: @Ghanima I hope that comment is directed at the person who was being abusive. I'm not impressed with people berating others seeking help on public forums, it's incredibly small minded and utterly frustrating. Thank you very much. Have a great day. Edit: I see you've deleted one of my replies to the other member of this forum because I told him to go away. Such triviality.

Comment: Actually I am addressing the both of you. Please note that we prefer that you flag hostile interaction towards you and disengage instead of piling on. Just because you have been wronged there is no reason to not stick to the Code yourself. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @Ghanima That's fair enough. I'll make sure to stay within the boundaries of the code. Thank you.